# Android Performance monitor on PC

Tags: android, performance, monitor, usage-statistics

Hello

For Windows Phone I use Windows Phone Developer Power Tools and I'm looking for alternative for Android. I want to monitor cpu, ram, I/O and others parameters from Android device(or virtual devices) connected to my PC. There is some application that has features I'm talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

With Android Studio [Android Monitor](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/android-monitor.html) you are able to monitor Memory, CPU|GPU and Network...

Comment: Can I install Android Monitor like stand alone application ? Can I start monitor other application don't develop in Android Studio ?

Comment: AFAIK you have to start Android Studio to use it. And then you'll be able to monitor applications you have developed

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more elaborate we are developing a performance monitoring platform for Android and iOS you can use to know what's going on with your app performance in prodcution. Monitoring thousand of different users with different devices and different Android OS versions or your own app different verisons.

The platform is still under development but you can join the mailing list if you want to know when the final release is published.

Once we finish the project you could see something like this:

[image]